# Model - Foreign Key db_column Naming Issue

Tags: python, django, model, foreign-keys

I am having an issue with the **db_column** parameter in Django. Lets say I have created a model in my models.py:

```
class Stats(models.Model):
    fk = models.ForeignKey(Game, db_column='fk_gameId')
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

and trying to make an insert to the table that is generated from the model, the sample code for the insert operation is like:

```
 dbQuery = Stats(fk_gameId = requestedGameId,
                 score = gameInfo['score'])

 dbQuery.save()
```

what happens is that the system throws the following error when executed:

> TypeError: 'fk_gameId' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

But if I change the the first parameter of the insert statement like below:

```
 dbQuery = Stats(fk_id = requestedGameId,
                 score = gameInfo['score'])

 dbQuery.save()
```

then it works flawlessly although the column name in the DB is "**fk_gameId**" as I defined it in the model.

Is it normal or am I missing something. Can you help me to understand what is the issue here? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `db_column` changes the name of the column *in the database*. It does not change the name of the model attribute used by Django.

Since you've defined the field as `fk = models.ForeignKey(...)`, the name of the field in Django is still `fk`, and the raw id field is named `fk_id`.

Comment: So is it not possible that I can change the field name in the Django? Will it always be myFieldNameForForeignKeyInModel + _id ?

Comment: The <field_name> + _id is hardcoded in `ForeignKey.get_attname()`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the info.

Comment: @Phyticist As @knbk said. You are changing the name of the column in DB with db_column. If you want to change the name in the model, you just have to write the name you want. But you wrote 'fk' as model name attribute, so when you query you have to use `fk_id`. If the attribute would be: 

`custom_name = models.ForeignKey(Game, db_column='fk_gameId')`

Then the query would be: `custom_name_id`.

Column names are not used in django queries, but attribute names.