# Django query to Postgres returning wrong column

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-models

I'm facing a strange problem maybe related with some cache that I cannot find.

I have the following Models:

```py
class Incubadores(models.Model):
    incubador = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    posicion = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Tareas(TimeStampedModel):
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=PRIORITIES, default='normal')
    incubador = models.ForeignKey(Incubadores, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, db_column='incubador')
    info = JSONField(null=True)
    datos = JSONField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('priority','modified','created')
```

I previously didn't have the argument `db_column`, so the Postgres column for that field was `incubador_id`
**I used the argument `db_column` to change the name of the column**, and then I run `python manage.py makemgrations` and python `manage.py migrate`, **but I'm still getting the column as `incubadores_id` whenever I perform a query** such as:

```py
>>> tareas = Tareas.objects.all().values()
>>> print(tareas)
<QuerySet [{'info': None, 'modified': datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 1, 15, 24, 58, 743803, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'created': datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 1, 15, 24, 58, 743803, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'datos': None, 'priority': 'normal', 'incubador_id': 'I1.1', 'id': 24}, {'info': None, 'modified': datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 1, 15, 25, 25, 49950, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'created': datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 1, 15, 25, 25, 49950, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'datos': None, 'priority': 'normal', 'incubador_id': 'I1.1', 'id': 25}]>
```

I need to modify this column name because I'm having other issues with Serializers. So the change is necessary.

- If I perform the same query in other Models where I've also changed the name of the default field. The problem is exactly the same.
- It happens both on the shell and on the code.
- I've tried with different queries, to make sure it's not related to Django lazy query system, but the problem is the same. I've also tried executing `django.db.connection.close()`.
- If I do a direct SQL query to PostgreSQL, it cannot find `incubador_id`, but only `incubador`, which is correct.

Anyone has any idea of what can be happening? I've already been 2 days with this problem and I cannot find a reason :( It's a very basic operation.

Thanks!

Comment: Your code is running fine. Django append `_id` itself for all foreign keys. If your have foreign key with name `abc`, in your database it will be saved as `abc_id`. `abc` will contain complete object of that foreign key.

Comment: You can try like this `Tareas.objects.all().values('id', 'incubador')`, then you can understand that it is running fine.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan, my original code includes `.values()` function, but I simplified the code in the example because it was happening anyway. The argument `db_column` removes the `_id` added by Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34022040/833881) will explain why this is happening.

Django's built-in serializers don't have this issue, but probably won't yield exactly what you're looking for:

```
>>> from django.core import serializers
>>> serializers.serialize("json", Tareas.objects.all())
'[{"model": "inc.tareas", "pk": 1, "fields": {"priority": "normal", "incubador": "test-i"}}]'
```

You *could* use the `fields` attribute here, which seems like it would give you what you're looking for.

You don't specify what your "other issues with Serializers" are, but my suggestion would be to write custom serialization code. Relying on something like `.values()` or even `serializers.serialize()` is a bit too implicit for me; writing explicit serialization code makes it less likely you'll accidentally break a contract with a consumer of your serialized data if this model changes.

*Note: Please try to make the example you provide [minimal and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I removed some fields to make this work with stock Django, which is why the serialized value is missing fields; the `_id` issue was still present without the third-party apps you're using, and was resolved with serializers. This also isn't specific to PG; it happens in sqlite as well.*

Comment: Thanks!! That was the reason, I was getting crazy.

Comment: So about the Serializers. I use DRF ones, and I'm having an error that I was trying to track down this way. But I think I'm finding the reason. Otherwise I'll post it too in a different thread.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like their serializers should be a good, explicit way to go.